Plotly customise y scaling factor
As one can see in the image, big price action yet candles are tiny. This problematic because this makes it hard to read the chart.

dfpl = df[20:40]
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=dfpl.index,
            open=dfpl.Open,
            high=dfpl.High,
            low=dfpl.Low,
            close=dfpl.Close
        )
    ]
)
fig.show()

is there some way to increase the scaling? thx.

You can increment the height of the figure, eg. fig.update_layout(height=900).
